# Trying to join two tables using left join, getting Analysis Exception Error for the input columns?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks

**I want all columns from Table 1 and only matching from Table2:**

```
drop table if exists temp.ms_time_decay_content;
create table temp.ms_time_decay_content as
select a.* , b.Category
from temp.ms_timedecay_adobe_Final a
Left Join temp.page_urls_6bded_csv b
on a.post_evar10 = b.Post_evar10;
```

**Getting below error**
[image]

Comment: the query looks fin to me. Maybe a spelling mistake in one of the table or column names (hidden space or something like that)? Hard to tell without actual data at hand.

Comment: Can you call everything (tables and columns) individually without the join?

Comment: it was a hidden space issue the query works. Thanks for your help.